# If row contains a certain word, copy the cell that contains that word

Tags: excel, if-statement, copy

I have a huge data set. I need to be able to search a row of data for certain words and if that word is contained in the row I need it to copy that whole cell. If that word is not contained in the row I need it to either stay blank or give me a 0. Either way is fine. Each word though also contains a number next to it, thats why I need it to copy the whole cell so that the number is included. It looks like this:

```
Row 1 -- 5 Notropis     6 Cyprinella     10 Catfish     7 Machrybopsis
```

.... and so on.

I need to search row 1 for example for the word "Cyprinella".. if this word exists (which is does in this example, I want it to output "6 Cyprinella".

If I searched this same row for the word "Plecostomous" (which is not contained in the example row, I want it to stay blank or say "0".

Comment: [THIS](http://www.siddharthrout.com/2011/07/14/find-and-findnext-in-excel-vba/) will get you started

Comment: Not much. I am so new to excel (at least more complex functions of excel) I don't even know where to begin.

Answer (score 1):

If your data is in Row1, your search term in say F4 then:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(1:1,MATCH("*"&F4,1:1,0)),"")
```

should work.

Comment: Tried this... didn't seem to work, however I am pretty new to excel and have not done very much with it.

Comment: Yes. My row 1 does not contain data that I want to search for. So say I want to search for the word "catfish" in row 20.. would I type it in:

=IFERROR(INDEX(1:20,MATCH("*"&catfish,1:20,0)),"") 

I guess I am unclear what the 1:20, "*" , and the final "" are all for... sorry I am such a noob.

Comment: HOLY MOLY... this worked... thank you so much!

OK another dumb question... If I want to now search every other row below this for the same word (catfish) how can I do this? I tried the obvious drag down or double click the little black square but it keeps changing the formula. For example my original formula is:

=IFERROR(INDEX(61:61,MATCH("*"&V1,61:61,0)),"")

When I extrapolate this down it changes it to 

=IFERROR(INDEX(62:62,MATCH("*"&V2,62:62,0)),"")
=IFERROR(INDEX(63:63,MATCH("*"&V3,63:63,0)),"")
..... and so on down the list... 

Is there any way to combat this? Thanks!!

Comment: Starts on Row 2 ends on Row 478

Columns K-U

Comment: This worked perfect!! Thank you so much for your time. This is literally going to save me weeks on this project.